# How to use the results of PocketSphinx voice-recognition code?

Tags: python, voice-recognition, pocketsphinx

I am trying to create a program that will constantly listen for speech, and if I say a certain string, it will call a certain function, example, if (string) then (function). I initially tried using Google Speech to Text API but could not get it to continuously listen (I even found a thread where someone said that Google Speech to Text API does not support continuous listening), so I reverted to PocketSphinx.
I have barely any code at all. I just have the initial beginner code you try out when you first install and run PocketSphinx (because I am a beginner). However, I don't want to do much. I created my own dictionary of a whopping 1 words, because I only want it to do one thing, and it reads it fine.

The problem I am having is actually using the string value that it constantly listens for to run future code. I don't know if I would have to add code to make it stop listening for a few moments after it hears a word in order for it to do something with the word is just heard or.... Also, I've heard that when you are comparing strings, you would use `.equals()` rather than `==`, correct me/elaborate if I'm wrong. I've tried it both ways. When I use `==`, nothing happens, it just continuously listens and prints the one word I say. When I use `.equals()`, I get an `AttributeError`.

***First Method:***

```
import os 
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech, get_model_path
speech = LiveSpeech(
    sampling_rate = 16000,
    hmm=os.path.join(get_model_path(), 'en-us'),
    lm='A:...(some random directory to a .lm file)',
    dic='A:...(some random directory to a .dic file)')
for code in speech:
    print(code)
    if code == "string":
        print("It works!")
```

***Second Method:***

```
import os 
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech, get_model_path
speech = LiveSpeech(
    sampling_rate = 16000,
    hmm=os.path.join(get_model_path(), 'en-us'),
    lm='A:...(some random directory to a .lm file)',
    dic='A:...(some random directory to a .dic file)')
for code in speech:
    print(code)
    if code.equals(myString): #myString is set to the word I say to it.
        print("It works!")
```

Second Method Error:
'LiveSpeech' object has no attribute 'equals'

Comment: python string doesn't have equals method. If you are not sure, you can use print(dir("python object")). In your case print(dir(code)) which prints out all the methods available for that object.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, I don't think I got anything useful out of that. I am having a hard time understanding what exactly is going on in the code. For example, what is the part that says hmm=os.path.join(get_model_path(), 'en-us).

Comment: I guess to elaborate my overall question, how do I manipulate "code", as in "for code in speech." How do I use it in comparisons and call functions and other programs based on what "code" is? Or, in other words, why can't I do that with the current script I have now? I mean, its recognizing it, every time I say something, it prints it, but I just can't do anything else with it.

Comment: hmm="path to the folder which contains trained model".

Comment: Okay, so I figured out my problem. I was just incorrectly converting it into a string. It works if you convert it into a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use live speech as if it were an iterator (like a list)

for example:

```
        for phrase in speech:
            text = phrase.hypothesis()
```